# How to access Edge Groups in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes, edges

I've been looking for a way to use edge groups in Geometry Nodes. Currently in Blender 3.6 the crease and sharp edge properties are accessible. Being able to access these two has been really useful, but it would be even better if bevel edge, freestyle edge and seams would also be available as edge groups in GN.

I found a bit of code in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281235/access-edge-data-in-geometry-nodes) and I've tried to apply it, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. This post is only 7 months old so I'm assuming that the answer is not outdated and there is something I'm doing wrong on my end. I'm a scripting nooblet so that seems pretty likely.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You could bevel the edges first, then use geonodes to compare before and after bevel to detect which edges had bevel weight assigned. It's harder to figure out the amount of the weight…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady If I understand it right that would work, but being able to access the edge data directly would be more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

but it works...

1. if you are a python beginner - you should write that in your question. We cannot know what your experience is.
2. if you are a geometry nodes beginner - you should write that in your question. We cannot know...

Assuming you are both of it because a) your python code cannot work that way and b) your geometry nodes modifier wasn't adapted...

1. you have to call a function so that it works. you just defined two functions, but they won't call themselves. You have to do that.
   so add

   ```
   apply_freestyle_attribute()
   ```

at the end of the text file, then run it.

Then you can go to your geometry nodes modifier and change it:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I'm inexperienced with Python. I've spent some time with GN though. The file I provided is my test file, I should have specified that in my question.