# Is setting the freestyle edge parameter via geonodes possible?

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes, freestyle

I have found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281235/access-edge-data-in-geometry-nodes) that addresses the reverse problem. But how do I **set** the freestyle parameter for my generated geometry? I tried looking in the spreadsheet for any additional attribute that may pop up when I manually set the Edge Freestyle, but there is nothing there.

I tried Storing Named Attribute on Point and Edge domains with names "freestyle_edge" and "use_freestyle_mark" set to TRUE. Doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to expose this parameter for geonodes to set procedurally?

Comment: I would try using this technique: [Geometry Nodes: set sharp or crease attribute for an edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247840/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thank you for your answer. I kinda dismissed the first time I saw this, and boy is this a convoluted workaround, but it's procedural and it might work! If it doesn't I'll just generate my own mesh wireframe. Cheers!